# Adding a property to every object property of an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, properties

In this example, how would I add a default `foobar: function() {}` property to each object inside of `Foo`?

```
Foo = {
    bar1: {
        foobar: function() {},
        width: "10m"
    },
    bar2: {
        foobar: function() {},
        width: "20m"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you organized your code a bit more to something like this?

```
function Bar(width) {

    this.foobar = function() {};
    this.width = width
}

Foo = {
    bar1: new Bar('10m'),
    bar2: new Bar('20m'),
    bar3: new Bar() //optional example
}
```

In this case, every `Bar` you create will come with `foobar()` as a default function, and you can pass `width` as an optional parameter.

### [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/f7qL2gr7/)

Comment: That works, but it would still be interesting to know if there is a way to do it in the original code snippet.